# Rxjava2 - how to cache Observable

Tags: caching, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am thinking the best way to cache a retrofit2 api response observable is with behaviorSubject.  This would emit the last item that was sent.  so i am trying to make a function that would take a boolean cache paramter to know if the response should be retrieved from cache or from retrofit2 call. The retrofit2 call just returns an observable.  But lets see what i want:

Here is the function before i implemented caching it just simply made a retrofit2 call to get a api response and someone subscribed to it somewhere else:

```
     public Observable<List<CountryModel>> fetchCountries() {
        CountriesApi countriesService = mRetrofit.create(CountriesApi.class);
        return countriesService.getCountries();

    }`
```

and here is what i want to achieve but having a hard time implementing a behaviorsubject to do it ? or how else can i cache the response at will ?

```
public Observable<List<CountryModel>> fetchCountries(boolean cache) {
          CountriesApi countriesService = mRetrofit.create(CountriesApi.class);

                if(!cache){
                  //somehow here i need to wrap the call in a behaviorsubject incase next time they want a cache - so need to save to cache here for next time around but how ?
                return countriesService.getCountries();
              }  else{
    behaviorsubject<List<CountryModel>>.create(countriesService.getCountries())
    //this isnt right.  can you help ?

                }
            }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to just cache the response (List) like this:

```
List<CountryModel> cachedCountries = null;

public Observable<List<CountryModel>> fetchCountries(boolean cache) {
    if(!cache || cachedCountries == null){
        CountriesApi countriesService = mRetrofit.create(CountriesApi.class);
        return countriesService
                .getCountries()
                .doOnNext(new Action1<List<CountryModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(List<CountryModel> countries) {
                        cachedCountries = countries;
                    }
                });
    } else {
        return Observable.just(cachedCountries);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not work, if you have multiple subscribers in the same time. Because the caching logic will run every time when you call the method, not when you subscribe on the observable. You should share the observable, or should put the method body in an Observable.deferred block.